# css animation does not work

Tags: css, animation

I'm just trying to implement a tutorial in webdesignmag, but it doesn't seem to be working. It's supposed to be "an entertaining loading animation for a better UX." I've tried it in Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m and Firefox 46.0.1. Does anyone see the mistake please?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testcss2.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<section id="loading">
<div><span></span></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body,#loading {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#loading > * {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

#loading > * {
    -webkit-animation-name: loadAnim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -animation-name: loadAnim;
    -animation-duration: 2s;
    -animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#loading > * > * {
    display: block;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid gray;
}

#loading > * > * {
    -webkit-animation-name: loadAnim; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -animation-name: loadAnim; 
    -animation-duration: 4s;
    -animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#loading > * > @-webkit-keyframes loadAnim {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    @keyframes loadAnim {
        from { transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to { transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }
}
```

Comment: First, the standard properties don't have a `-` before them. Second, the nesting structure of the keyframes rules is wrong. Third, you shouldn't add selectors like `#loading > * > ` before `@-webkit-keyframes` as it has no meaning. Fixing all these your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `#loading > * >` before you animation code. Changing it to this does the trick:

```
@-webkit-keyframes loadAnim {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes loadAnim {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

See this fiddle as reference: 
https://jsfiddle.net/y8q3wdv9/

Comment: *thank you*! I don't why they left that in the magazine.

Answer (score 0):

1. `@keyframes loadAnim {}` shouldn't be embedded within `@-webkit-keyframes loadAnim {}`
2. The `animation` properties shouldn't have `-` in front of them.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh2dyft9/